Set env variables from the output of entrypoint script in dockerfile
I am trying to fetch few key value pairs from the vault and pass them to kubernetes container in the form of env variables.
I have a Dockerfile which call the entrypoint shell script and
Dockerfile:
COPY --from=stage /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=stage /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/.env.production ./



EXPOSE 5555


ENTRYPOINT ["/app/scripts/script.sh"]
ENV val=${val}

RUN echo ${val}
CMD [ "npm","start" ]

The script.sh is estblishing the connection from vault and grabbing the values for the secrets
#!/bin/bash

    echo "retrive variables from vault "
    export val=$(getParameter "val" "${VAULT_URL}/${xxx}/${ENVIRONMENT}/${dddd}/val")
    echo ${val}

The out put of the script.sh returns the value of command echo ${val} so script seems to run fine
But the Dockerfile returns the output of echo command RUN echo ${val} as null and doesn't set it as env variable
Can anyone help here how we can set the output of the script.sh present as ENTRYPOINT to env variables.

The entrypoint is run at container start time. the RUN command is run at image build time. So it is no wonder that echo ${val} returns nothing.

Also, you may want to look into the interaction of ENTRYPOINT and CMD as described here (docs.docker.com).

The Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT and CMD directives don't actually run those commands; they just record those as data in the image when the container is actually run.  While they're frequently at the end of the Dockerfile (logically they "happen" after everything else in the Dockerfile is executed) there's no particular reason they need to be.  But putting them earlier doesn't cause them to be actually run.
If you're just trying to get the secret values available to the Node application when it runs, you should add a line to the end of the entrypoint wrapper script
exec "$@"

When Docker eventually runs the container, the CMD is passed as arguments to the ENTRYPOINT.  This line causes the entrypoint script to replace itself (exec) with the arguments it's passed ("$@"); that is, to switch over to the CMD as the main container command.
If you do need this during the build, it's hard to get the results of a command persisted in environment variables (and the credentials may depend on the current user, and you don't want them persisted in the image in plain text in any case).  There's no rule that says you have to use this script only as a Docker entrypoint script, though; so long as you pass a command as arguments to it, you can reuse it as needed.
RUN /app/scripts/script.sh npm build


I simply need when I deploy my container using K8 the variables should be stored as env variable of the container. I tried the above steps but nothing worked exec "$@" as well RUN /app/scripts/script.sh npm build

The environment variables should be set in the process.  They won't be visible in docker inspect or kubectl get pod output, and that's okay.  With the exec "$@" line, try docker run --rm your-image env to dump out the main process's effective environment.
